# Issues with deploying ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API

Tags: .net-core, iis, windows-server-2019

I'm creating a simple API that will create a PDF letter based on data passed into the API via the body.

For simplicity sake, I've got the API working just fine on my local machine via IIS Express.

I'm now attempting to deploy it on our web server (Server 2019).

In publishing the API, I've selected `net5.0` as the Target Framework, deployment mode is set to self-contained, and the target runtime is set to win-x64.

I've logged into our web server, copied my publish folder contents into a new folder (`D:\Sites\WebSite\Mailer`) [Mailer is the API reference - so it should be website.com\mailer\pdfmaker is the designed url that again works fine on my local machine running IIS in Visual Studio 2019].

I've gone into IIS under Application Pools, and created a PDFMaker app pool, set to "No Managed Code" that is started.

I've gone under the WebSite, and added an application named Mailer using the PDFMaker app pool, pointed to the correct physical path (`D:\Sites\Websites\Mailer`) using pass-through authentication.

I would assume that all should work, but whenever I try to access the API, (using Postman), I get a HTTP 404 Not Found error.

So, what am I missing?

For the record, I've also tried using framework-dependent as the deployment mode, and Portable as the target runtime, to no avail.

Comment: What about the security of the api? Did you pass/setup the api endpoints with any sort of security that may require when invoking via Postman or any client. Is that a POST method or GET?

Comment: There shouldn't be a security issue as it's set for pass-through authentication...  Postman returns a 404 on both POST and GET, and while the POST method is what generates the PDF there is a get method that returns json that tells you the API is working...

Comment: Do they work locally from that server, like `localhost/Mailer/pdfmaker`? May be, testing GET call

Comment: I get an error message saying Windows cannot find '\\localhost:443\mailer\pdfmaker' as well as '\\192.168.101.60:443\mailer\pdfmaker'  when trying to access it via webpage on the server

Comment: 1. You might run a report to see if anything is missing, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html 2. .NET 5 reached end of life a while ago, so you should upgrade to .NET 6 or 8.

Comment: @MusicalCoder - then thats where you'd want to try to find a solution and may not be with the .net publish. Certainly .NET 5 is already EOL, you'd want to go with .NET 8 to be on a better state. If I may ask, what are your HTTP methods or name as endpoints followed by your api base uri? like, is your POST method is named `pdfmaker` or something else?

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.